# Google Play Billing V6 show error DF-DFERH-01

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Hi I am integrating Google Play Billing Library on my project on a `fragment` in android studio to sell a subscription, I alrready make the set up in the Google Play Console uploading my app in internal test and making the subscription basic plan, then I continued to make the logic process in my app following the steps in the documentation, everything is fine, I checked the product list and it has the subscription´s information, but when the app tries to show up the google play window it appears the next error message:

[image: errorImage]

I searched in internet and they said to clear the data, cache of the google play store and google play service and restart the phone I did it but it did not work, I open another app with subscription and it shows the window of the google play subscription without problem, so I dont think the problem is the google play store

[image: otherAppSubscription]

I have tried a lot of things, download the app from google play store (internal test), changing a fragment for an activity, using the downgrade version of the libray and nothing work, I share you my code, thanks in advance

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sin_anuncios, container, false);
        PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
                // To be implemented in a later section.
            }
        };

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getContext())
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build();

        connectToGooglePlayBilling();

        return view;
    }

    private void connectToGooglePlayBilling(){

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {

                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    getProductDeatils();

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se pudo conectar a GooglePlay, revisa tu conexion a internet.\nIntentando conectarse nuevamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                connectToGooglePlayBilling();
                
            }
        });

    }


    private void getProductDeatils(){

        QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams =
                QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                        .setProductList(
                                ImmutableList.of(
                                        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                                .setProductId("version_sin_anuncios")
                                                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                                .build()))
                        .build();

        Activity activity = getActivity();

        billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                queryProductDetailsParams,
                new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                    public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                         List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                        // check billingResult
                        // process returned productDetailsList

                        if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && productDetailsList != null){
                            TextView descripcion = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSinAnuncios);
                            descripcion.setText(productDetailsList.get(0).getDescription());

                            Button BotonSinAnuncios = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSinAnuncios);
                            BotonSinAnuncios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v)
                                {
                                    Log.d("GoogleBillingService", "onBillingSetupFinished: billingResult: " + billingResult);
                                    Log.d("GoogleBillingService", "Product detatils: " + productDetailsList.get(0));

                                    ImmutableList productDetailsParamsList =
                                            ImmutableList.of(
                                                    BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                                            // retrieve a value for "productDetails" by calling queryProductDetailsAsync()
                                                            .setProductDetails(productDetailsList.get(0))
                                                            // to get an offer token, call ProductDetails.getSubscriptionOfferDetails()
                                                            // for a list of offers that are available to the user
                                                            .setOfferToken(String.valueOf(productDetailsList.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()))
                                                            .build()
                                            );


                                    BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                            .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
                                            .build();


                                    // Launch the billing flow
                                    billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);

                                }
                            });


                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error often occurs when incorrect data is passed to the Billing Library.

In your case, please find the relevant `offerToken`:

`String offerToken = productDetailsList.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getOfferToken();`

(Of course, this is just an example, and I'm omitting various checks. I'm assuming that the first product is a subscription and that your desired offer is the first in the list returned by `getSubscriptionOfferDetails()`.You should use your custom logic to find the right offer.)

Afterward, try removing the line `.setOfferToken(String.valueOf(productDetailsList.get(0).getSubscriptionOfferDetails()))` with `setOfferToken(offerToken)`

Comment: Thanks man, you are right I needed to get the token from the list